# Tree node with arbitrary many child nodes in C

Tags: c, pointers, tree, structure

I'm trying to implement a node structure in C that can have arbitrary many child nodes. I wanted to do this idea by using a pointer to a pointer to a struct instead of using an array:

```
struct Node {
    char name[10];  // Name of the node.
    int data;       // The data it holds.
    struct Node *parent; // The parent node.
    struct Node **child; //
};
```

(I don't know if this is the best or even a good but I'm just playing around to learn C better).
I also implemented a `print` function that prints the members:

```
void print(struct Node node);
```

(I know this only prints one node so it wouldn't work for a node with multiple child-nodes).
However, when I try to use this in a `main` function I get a `segmentation fault (core dump)`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char name[10];  // Name of the node.
    int data;       // The data it holds.
    struct Node *parent; // The parent node.
    struct Node **child; //
};

void print(struct Node node) {
    printf("Name: %s\n", node.name);
    printf("Data: %d\n", node.data);
    printf("Parent: %s\n", (*node.parent).name);
    printf("Children: %s\n", (**node.child).name);
}

int main() {
    struct Node n1 = { "Parent", 1, NULL, NULL };
    struct  Node n2 = { "Child1", 2, &n1, NULL };
   
    *n1.child = &n2;
   
    print(n1);
    print(n2);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Can anybody see what I'm doing wrong here and what I should do instead?

Kind regards,

Edit:

Actually what I wanted to achieve was to create the child member like this (I'm using an example with an array of integers to illustrate what I mean):

```
int *p = malloc(sizeof(int));
*p =1;
*(p+1)=2;
```

but instead of p pointing to integers having it point to pointers to struct Node. Is this doable?

Comment: n1.child is a null pointer so you cannot assign anything to the *memory pointed to by it*.

Comment: Aha thank you, how should initialize n1 then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get a segmentation fault because you do not test if the `parent` node is valid, nor if the `child` node is a valid pointer, nor that the pointer it points to is valid too. The initialization of `n1.child[0]` is incorrect too.

- `*n1.child = &n2;` has undefined behavior because `n1.child` is a null pointer.
- `printf("Parent: %s\n", (*node.parent).name);` has undefined behavior for `n1`;
- `printf("Children: %s\n", (**node.child).name);` has undefined behavior for `n2`.

Alos note that it is idiomatic in C to pass structure pointers rather than copies of structures to functions such as `print`.

Here is a modified version, assuming `child`, if not `NULL` points to a `NULL` terminated array of `node` pointers.

**EDIT**: I added an `add_child` function to illustrate how to construct trees from individual nodes.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct Node {
    char name[10];  // Name of the node.
    int data;       // The data it holds.
    struct Node *parent; // The parent node.
    struct Node **child; // if not NULL, points to a NULL terminated array of pointers.
};

void print(const struct Node *node) {
    if (node) {
        printf("Name: %s\n", node->name);
        printf("Data: %d\n", node->data);
        if (node->parent) {
            printf("Parent: %s\n", node->parent->name);
        }
        if (node->child) {
            printf("Children:");
            for (int i = 0; node->child[i]; i++) {
                printf("%s %s", i > 0 ? "," : "", node->child[i]->name);
            }
            printf("\n");
        }
    }
}

// add a child node to a parent's child list.
// return 0 upon success or an error code on failure
int add_child(struct Node *parent, struct Node *chid) {
    if (parent == NULL)
        return 1;
    if (child == NULL)
        return 2;
    size_t nchild = 0;
    if (parent->child != NULL) {
        while (parent->child[nchild] != NULL)
            nchild++;
    }
    struct Node *new_child = realloc(parent->child, (nchild + 2) * sizeof(*new_child));
    if (new_child == NULL)
        return 3;
    parent->child = new_child;
    parent->child[nchild++] = child;
    parent->child[nchild] = NULL;
    child->parent = parent;
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    struct Node n1 = { "Parent", 1, NULL, NULL };
    struct Node n2 = { "Child1", 2, NULL, NULL };
    struct Node n3 = { "Child2", 3, NULL, NULL };

    add_child(&n1, &n2);
    add_child(&n1, &n3);
   
    print(&n1);
    print(&n2);
    print(&n3);
   
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you! I edited the post to clarify what I'm trying to achieve (sorry for not having specied this more clearly from the beginning). By the way, way is it preferable to pass pointers to struct to functions (It seems to me that it wasn't necessary in the print function above)?

Comment: @user202542: Your approach is correct: I updated the answer to illustrate how to add child nodes. The `print` function could indeed take a `struct Node` by value, but it is cumbersome and potentially inefficient. It is much preferred to pass a pointer. Note that in this implementation, a null pointer is accepted and ignored, whereas with the pass by value approach, you would need to check all node pointers before passing the value they point to.

Answer (score 0):

You've commented out the print function, but you're trying to call it to print the nodes.

Comment: Sorry this was a mistake, I edited it (I get the error without the commenting).

Answer (score 0):

n1.child is NULL pointer, you dereference it here *n1.child = &n2;
this why you get segfault, just make child normal pointer not double pointer it will solve the problem

```
struct Node {
char name[10];  // Name of the node.
int data;       // The data it holds.
struct Node *parent; // The parent node.
struct Node *child; //};

void print(struct Node node) {
printf("Name: %s\n", node.name);
printf("Data: %d\n", node.data);
printf("Parent: %s\n", (*node.parent).name);
printf("Children: %s\n", (*node.child).name);}

int main() {
struct Node n1 = { "Parent", 1, NULL, NULL };
struct  Node n2 = { "Child1", 2, &n1, NULL };

n1.child = &n2;

print(n1);
print(n2);

return 0;}
```